# gitignore: ignore newly added filed to .gitignore

Tags: git

I wanted to add few more files to gitignore. And want them to be ignored in the past/present and future

I found many answers. The most common answer i found was

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

Here what i understand is, git rm is removing all the the files from cache and then adding all back them back using git add. and then commit

I don't want to create  a new commit as done here, then how  can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to add few more files to gitignore.

That's fine.

> And want them to be ignored in the past

That's not.  You can't have that.  No existing commit can ever be changed.  (But see below.)

> [and] present and future

You *can* have that.  You just have to remove them from the *next* commit you make.

> Here what i understand is, git rm is removing all the the files from cache ...

Yes, though the entity from which they are being removed here is usually called either the *index* or the *staging area*.  (These both mean the same thing.)  The term *cache* is left over from a decade ago.  This entity—the thing called the index or staging area—mostly contains the *proposed next* commit, ready to be made.  By altering its contents, you alter what you propose to commit.

A file that is in the index / staging-area *right now* (i.e., has not yet been `git rm --cached`) is called *tracked*.  A tracked file is never ignored.  A file that is no longer in the index (after `git rm --cached`) is *untracked*, if it still exists in the work-tree (as these do).  An untracked file can be untracked and *not* ignored, or untracked and ignored.

> ... and then adding all back them back using git add

Yes, except that *all* is too strong: the `git add .` step adds all *non-ignored* files, by copying them into the index.  This replaces any previous version in the index, or—if the file was untracked—introduces the file into the index so that the file is now tracked.  Either way, after the `add`, these files are tracked, and the hidden-away copies of the files that are in the index match the copies of the files that you can view (and modify) that exist in your work-tree.

Hence, the two-command sequence `git rm -r --cached .; git add .` removes all files from the index (so that no files are tracked, and if you committed at this point you would get a truly empty commit—one that when checked out, has no files in it) and then puts back only those files that do not match the `.gitignore` rules.

> I don't want to create a new commit as done here ...

At some point, you *have* to.  Git stores—and transfers—only the *commits*.  The index is a *temporary* area, in which you build the next commit.  Checking out any existing commit replaces whatever is in the index, with whatever is in the commit you check out.

(Meanwhile, your work-tree is yours to do with as you will—but `git checkout` will, after copying a commit to the index, proceed to copy the index to the work-tree.  The reason for that is obvious: the files in the index are hidden, invisible.  They are stored in a format that only Git can work with.  You presumably want to *see* and *work with* your files, in their ordinary every-day format.  Git must copy the files to your work-tree for you to be able to do that.)

#### Rewriting history

In Git, history *is* commits; commits *are* history.  That is all there is to history.

Each commit has its own unique hash ID, some big ugly string of letters and digits like `08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468`.  No *other* commit ever has this hash ID, and `08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468` always means *this* commit.  As mere humans, we usually can't remember these random-looking hash IDs, so we have Git remember them for us, using branch and tag names.  Each branch or tag name holds exactly one hash ID.

Each commit itself also holds some number of additional hash IDs.  These hash IDs are the *parent commits* of the commit in question.  So if `08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468` has parent `07f25ad8b235c2682a36ee76d59734ec3f08c413`, then `07f25ad8b235c2682a36ee76d59734ec3f08c413` must come right before it.  Meanwhile commit `07f25ad8b235c2682a36ee76d59734ec3f08c413` has another parent hash ID.  That parent (grandparent) commit has another parent (the great-grandparent), and so on.

By starting at the hash ID of the *last* commit—as stored in a branch name—we, or Git, find the history.  The history *is* commits; commits *are* the history.  A branch name just tells us where the most-recent-end of history is, so that we can look back towards the start of history.

Occasionally, however, we find ourselves with a Git repository in which a bunch of existing commits are what we would call "bad" for whatever reason.  It's important to remember that whatever we do, we **cannot change those existing commits**.  But if we *find* commits by starting at the end ... well, what happens if we *copy* some, or maybe **every**, commit that exists in the repository?

For instance, suppose we have just eight commits, all in a nice neat row, like this:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The name `master` finds us the *last* commit, `H` (whatever its real hash ID is).  `H` has a hash ID in it, which finds `G`.  `G` finds `F`, which finds `E`, and so on back to `A`.  `A` is the very first commit, so unlike the rest of the commits, it has *no* parent: it's where history starts.

Let's walk the history all the way back to `A`, then take that commit out of the freezer (as it were) and turn it into something we can work with.  Then, let's fix up that commit however we like, so that it's "good" instead of "bad".  Then we'll make a *new* commit from it, but this time, one that has *no parent*:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master

A'  <-- new-master
```

The new commit has a different hash ID—`A'` instead of `A`—but like `A`, is a *first* commit.  We'll use the name `new-master` to remember the actual hash ID.

Now let's take `B` out and fix it up so that it, too, is improved.  Let's make a new commit from that, with its parent set to `A'` rather than `A`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master

A'-B'  <-- new-master
```

We update `new-master` to remember the new hash ID of `B'`.  Now we repeat for `C` through `H` so that we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master

A'-B'-C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- new-master
```

We've now *copied* every commit!  **Note that we have not changed any of the existing commits at all.**  They still exist, with their same old hash IDs.  But now we do the one thing we still can: we *change the name `master`* so that instead of remember hash ID `H`, it remembers hash ID `H'`.  We can then *delete* the name `new-master`, and we now have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]

A'-B'-C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- master
```

Since we *find* commits by looking at the hash ID in the name `master`, then looking at that commit (`H'`), then looking at its parent (`G'`) and continuing on back through the parent chains, we *see* the new, updated history.

If `A` and `B` were good, and all our problems started at `C`, we'd leave `A` and `B` in place and rewrite starting from `C`, so as to get:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
    \
     C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- master
```

which, since we can't *find* commit `H` any more, would look like this when viewed:

```
A--B--C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- master
```

This process—duplicating-but-fixing-up commits with the fixed-up commits pointing to their fixed-up parents—does not by itself *change* history at all.  But if we swap the *labels* around, so that the branch names identify the *new* history, and if weak and feeble humans are unable to notice that some or all of the hash IDs have mysteriously changed, why then, we *think* that the history has been changed.

This updated Git repository, with new history (and old still present!—any old but abandoned commits can normally eventually be thrown out but Git will take some time to get around to this), is *not compatible* with any clones of the original history.  Git, you see, *does* pay attention to the hash IDs.  Git won't forget that these are new and different commits.  If you allow a `git pull` to connect an old clone to a rewritten-history one, you often just re-combine the histories.  **Be very careful when rewriting history.**  Everyone with the old history must throw out their old Git repository and clone the new one instead.  Otherwise you end up with:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
    \                 \
     C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I   <-- master
```

which reintroduces all the history you *thought* you had discarded.

(It's somewhat rare to find cases where rewriting history is worthwhile, in my opinion.  But Git is just a tool-set, and will let you do this if you want.)

Comment: `That's not. You can't have that. No existing commit can ever be changed. (But see below.)`: Assuming in  my branch i have ten commits. I have commit my .gitignore file in the first commit. Instead of chaning .gitignore in the tenth commit, i go back to first commit and change. Will that effect all the other commits

Comment: You *can't* change *any* existing commit. You *can* copy the first commit to a new first commit. The existing second commit still points back to the existing first commit: that's part of the second commit, and cannot be changed.

Comment: i can change an existing commit using `git rebase -i --root`.

Comment: No, you can't. You get a *copy*, a new and different commit. That's what `git rebase` does: it copies selected commits. With `--root`, it includes the root commit (`A` above).

Comment: Yes, thats true